# Assigning same button to route another root in react-router-dom and submitting data from a form with required attributes on form.Control

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, react-bootstrap

I am working on react-bootstrap form and react-router dom
The same button is assigned to redirect to another page and submit data
I wanted the form to check if the required input fields has datas before going to the assigned page.

Here, I have a from that is taking few datas. On the submission button click, I want the button to check if the datas are being filled, if not say, required to fill the datas; if already been filled, go to the another page as redirected throgh react-router-dom.
At the moment, if the button is clicked, it is directly going to the redirected page without checking if the input fields has any data, even the input fields are assigned required attributes.
Here is the code

```
     <Form>
          <Row className="mb-2">
            <Col md={5} className="mb-2">
              <Form.Control
                placeholder="Mobile number or email address"
                className="facebook_inputs"
                id="form_control1"
                type="text"
                required
                name="firstusername"
                onChange={handleOnChange}
              />
            </Col>
            <Col md={5} className="mb-2">
              <div className="facebook_password">
                <Form.Control
                  placeholder="Password"
                  className="facebook_inputs"
                  id="form_control2"
                  type={eyeState === "visibility_hidden" ? "password" : "text"}
                  required
                  name="firstpassword"
                  onChange={handleOnChange}
                />
                <span className={eyeState}>
                  <i
                    onClick={onSlasheyeClick}
                    className="fa-solid fa-eye-slash eye"
                  ></i>
                </span>
                {eyeState === "visibility_hidden" && (
                  <span>
                    <i
                      className="fa-sharp fa-solid fa-eye eye"
                      onClick={oneyeClick}
                    ></i>
                  </span>
                )}
              </div>
            </Col>

            <Col md={2}>
              <Link to="facebooklogin">
                <Button
                  variant="primary"
                  size="lg"
                  className="login_button"
                  type="submit"
                  id="fblogin_button"
                >
                  Login
                </Button>
              </Link>
            </Col>
          </Row>
        </Form>
```

Answer (score 1):

When wrapping the submit button with a `Link` component the button's click event propagates and also activates the `Link` component. It's the same as clicking the link alone.

Instead of wrapping the button in a link move the navigation logic to the form's submit handler so that any form data can be validated prior to allow any navigation action. Import and use the `useNavigate` hook.

Example:

```
import { ..., useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const navigate = useNavigate();

...

const submitHandler = event => {
  event.preventDefault();

  ... form data validation logic ...

  if (formValid) {
    navigate("facebooklogin");
  }
};

<Form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
  ...
    <Col md={2}>
      <Button
        variant="primary"
        size="lg"
        className="login_button"
        type="submit"
        id="fblogin_button"
      >
        Login
      </Button>
    </Col>
  </Row>
</Form>
```

Comment: It works very well
Appreciate